# Toggling the color of a div box using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of this div box whenever it gets clicked. For some reason the funtcion only works whenever I click on the same div box twice. Am I missing something?

```js
function selected_platz(platz_id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(platz_id).style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 168, 0)")
    {
        document.getElementById(platz_id).style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById(platz_id).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 168, 0)";
}
```

```html
<div class='div_platz' onclick='selected_platz(this.id)' id='".$row['platz_id']."'>".$counter."</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine, the color changes the first time IO click it.

Comment: `element.style` refers to inline styles only (styling via the HTML attribute `style="background-color: blue;"`). Use CSS classes instead.

Comment: dont use `.style` in 2022. Use `classList.toggle('class-name')` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.style` refers to **inline styles** only (styling via the HTML attribute `style="background-color: blue;"`). Initially, your element doesn't have such an attribute.

Use a `selected` CSS class instead, and toggle that on click:

```css
.div_platz { background-color: rgb(0, 168, 0); }
.div_platz.selected { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class='div_platz' onclick='this.classList.toggle("selected")' id='".$row['platz_id']."'>".$counter."</div>
```

It would be even better if you also didn't use inline event listeners. Instead attach the listener via Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let places = document.querySelectorAll('div.div_platz');
  for (const place of places) {
    place.addEventListener('click', function() {
      place.classList.toggle('selected');
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.div_platz { background-color: rgb(0, 168, 0); }
.div_platz.selected { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class='div_platz' id='".$row['platz_id']."'>".$counter."</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the color through CSS and toggle a class with a blue backgroun-color with `.classList.togle('class-name')`

```js
function selected_platz(platz_id) {
  document.getElementById(platz_id).classList.toggle('bg-blue');
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(0, 168, 0);
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='div_platz' onclick='selected_platz(this.id)' id='".$row[' platz_id ']."'>".$counter."</div>
```